# send mail from Gmail through outlook365 account via SMTP

Tags: outlook, smtp, gmail, single-sign-on

My company is moving from Exchange 2010 to Outlook 365. Although Outlook 365 still allows to redirect mails to another address, like my Gmail account, it now requires SSO authentication to send mail via SMTP protocol. Given the fact that Gmail doesnt have SSO auth to SMTP, I wont be able to keep using my Gmail account to receive/send work mails (just receive them).

Is there any alternative to interface Gmail to a SMTP server that requires SSO?

I've seen miniOrange, however I'm not sure it provides a SMTP relay with SSO between Gmail and Outlook 365, such that I could use a password-based miniOrange SMTP that connects to my company SMTP with SSO.